# CSS animation not working in LWC in Safari

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, animations

The bottom right spinner here:

[CSS animation in LWC not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253614/css-animation-in-lwc-not-working)

animates in Chrome and Safari as static HTML. But when added into an LWC - meaning the content is dynamically added to the DOM - it animates in Chrome but does not animate in Safari.

I presume the problem is unrelated to this fixed problem [CSS animation in LWC not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253614/css-animation-in-lwc-not-working), and has more to do with Safari. Things I found Googling such as adding a start delay didn't help:

```
animation: cssload-dots 3.25s infinite 0.01s ease-in-out;
```

I think this is worth flagging that here for anyone thinking of adding animations to their LWC. And if there is a reliable answer to how to fix this, that would be great too...

Don't see any mention of Safari in the change history of the [SLDS spinner](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/blob/b0b8e7df99d959d077ab25428a8a71d1d9a483e6/ui/components/spinners/base/_index.scss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Safari (webkit) behaves a bit unexpectedly when the animation is dynamically added. After many, many, many tries, the smallest change I could get to work was from this:

```
    animation: cssload-dots 3.25s infinite ease-in-out;
        -o-animation: cssload-dots 3.25s infinite ease-in-out;
        -ms-animation: cssload-dots 3.25s infinite ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation: cssload-dots 3.25s infinite ease-in-out;
        -moz-animation: cssload-dots 3.25s infinite ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes cssload-dots {
```

to this:

```
    animation: cssload-dots-x 3.25s infinite ease-in-out;
        -o-animation: cssload-dots 3.25s infinite ease-in-out;
        -ms-animation: cssload-dots 3.25s infinite ease-in-out;
        /* -webkit-animation: cssload-dots 3.25s infinite ease-in-out; */
        -moz-animation: cssload-dots 3.25s infinite ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes cssload-dots-x {
```

meaning both a unique `keyframes` name was needed *and* the webkit style needed to be removed.

If you are including animation CSS in your LWC, be sure to test with Safari.